# Widget broken after site switched to https

Tags: civicontribute

I changed my wordpress site to use https
Now the widgets for donations do not load anymore. they only display the placeholder text

any ideas?

thanks
Conte

Answer (score 3):

Two separate problems with the same source, which is that your widget is static HTML and Javascript that you copied and pasted in place.  It *does not* update by itself when you make changes.

If you just see the placeholder text, it means that the Javascript is failing to get the current totals.

1. Your widget may be trying to connect to your site, failing because it's not connecting through HTTPS.  Depending upon how you implemented HTTPS, these sorts of connections may fail unless you specify the https://... URL.
2. Your browser may be refusing to connect via an insecure protocol.  Recent versions of browsers will simply exclude Javascript and CSS that comes through HTTP when you're on an HTTPS page.

The solution to either problem is the same: fix the widget.  You can read through the widget's code and replace each instance of "http://" with "https://".  Alternatively, you can simply go manage your contribution page, go to the widget tab, copy the code, and paste it in place of the old code.

Comment: thanks. the crm is at crm.mydomain.com
however this subdomain is not https
do I have to change that to make it work?

Comment: You might--in this case you're probably dealing with issue #2.  Connecting to a script via an insecure protocol from a secure page undermines the security of the page as a whole.  The solution would be to implement HTTPS on your CRM domain.  However, while you're at it, you might consider moving your CiviCRM site to your WordPress installation. By having them separate, you're giving up valuable integration options such as the CiviCRM Contribution Page Widget plugin, which would handle all of this automatically. https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-contribution-page-widget/

Comment: With my server I have no change to make the subdomain https too and I also cannot get a second certificate. Any other ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you should switch hosting.  Also, do you know why you don't have CiviCRM running on your WordPress site?  Running from a single site would solve your problem as well.

Comment: had civicrm on drupal before it even came out for wordpress. works so well :)